# How can you rid your house of 'Sick Building Syndrome'?

Tags: painting, odors, precautions

It's a rite of passage - You and your spouse are expecting, and it's your responsibility to paint the baby's room.

But before you do so, make sure that you use only latex/low VOC paint, keep the room well-ventilated for at least a few days, and try to keep the pregnant mother away from the room while you're doing work.

Well, I did all of that. Unfortunately, my wife appears to be experiencing ['Sick Building Syndrome'](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sick_building_syndrome).

My Question: How can I remedy this situation? Can I buy an appliance to rid the air of harmful particles? Can I hire a professional to clean the air?

Also, please bear in mind, I'm not experiencing any discomfort myself. My wife however, has a dry cough, some asthma symptoms, and a burning sensation in her eyes.

Comment: are you sure it's just the new paint you used?

Comment: **Please consult a doctor.**  This could be a serious medical condition, and cannot realistically be diagnosed or treated by an internet community (even if that community happens to be totally AWESOME).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry there is no such thing as 'Sick Building Syndrome', it is just a **lazy way to label a problem that is not understood**.

So you first need to find out in detail what is causing the problem.

Given that your wife is expecting, it may have nothing to do with the building at all…..

A doctor may be able to do tests and give you a list of the things she is sensitive to, so you have somewhere to start – it could just be something as simple as dust you liberated while clearing the room to paint it and nothing to do with the paint.

Answer (score 4):

You can get an air purifier that utilizes a HEPA filter and an Ioniser.

[HEPA Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEPA)

- Helps remove particles as small as 0.5micron, dust and other particles.

[IONISER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_ioniser)

- Blasts the area with negative ions that binds at molecular level to odours, particles, chemicals, smoke, pollen, etc. Causes these particles to become heavy and fall the floor. You will need to vacuum frequently (with a HEPA filter installed) to recycle the air.

**DO NOT**

Buy an air purifier that produces [Ozone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone)  (O3)

- Ozone, in theory is supposed to kill viruses, bacteria and other living airborne particles. This however has an adverse effect on people too! Especially pregnant woman! Studies prove that only HIGH concentrations of Ozone will effectively kill bacteria, but it also kills humans. Some air purifiers create ozone by splitting air air molecules (which rebind to a neighbouring oxygen molecule causing a Triatomic state o3) using high voltage static discharge (and has that smell after a heavy lightning storm) Small amounts do nothing and is just a selling gimmick - but used in an enclosed room could cause sickness to people.

**HINTS**

- Flush your hush with clean air, jsut open all the windows (make sure your partner is not in any drafts) for a few hours.
- Also could be other reasons your partner is feeling sick, and not necessarily from your recent work or house - Please do consult a doctor as soon as possible.